# Plugin for bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any gem available for implementing the new bootstrap ?? I am using

> `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails if you would like to use Sass everywhere and not switch to less for bootstrap alone. This one has also been updated for 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Comment: Always best to provide an explanation in case the link changes

Answer (score 0):

I've published a beta version of [rails_bootstrap_navbar](https://github.com/julescopeland/Rails-Bootstrap-Navbar) - a gem for easy generation of navbars using bootstrap 2.0

I'd recommend sticking with bootstrap-sass for importing the boilerplate code.